# Java - How to download a file using UDP connection?

Tags: java, udpclient

I want to test connection by uploading & downloading using UDP connection.

I done with uploading. How can I do downloading a file using UDP connection.

Please help me on this.

Comment: "UDP connection" is an oxymoron: UDP is a *connectionless* protocol.

Comment: I know UDP is connectionless and not a reliable connection but I want to do it for connection test.

Comment: But there is no connection to test? You can test reachability. But if you have already communicated via TCP with the machine in question, you already proved it reachable.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Wikipedia article on UPD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol):

*It has no handshaking dialogues, and thus exposes any unreliability of the underlying network protocol to the user's program. As this is normally IP over unreliable media, there is no guarantee of delivery, ordering or duplicate protection.*

Given that a stream of bytes representing a file would need to be guaranteed, ordered and duplicate aware UDP is not a suitable protocol for file transfer.

You could of course implement your own protocol over UDP that introduces guaranteed delivery, ordering and duplicate detection, but why bother when TCP already does what you need.

Comment: Hi Nick Holt, Thanks for ur reply. I want to test the both TCP and UDP connection. So I done with TCP. Now I want to do with UDP. And do you any sample code or link to refer to achieve this?

Comment: It won't work with UDP.  UDP is a broadcast protolcol, not something that allows two-way data transfer.